# Do bulky bases participate in substitution reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, elimination

I see how bulky bases influence the regioselectivity of E2 and E1 reactions. I do not see very much content on the involvement of bulky bases in substitution reactions.

I know that bulky bases like *t*-BuOK are generally not involved in substitution reactions because the *t*-BuO<sup>−</sup> ion would prefer to take a β-hydrogen instead. Are any  substitution reactions possible, and if so, what mechanism would be seen in substitution reactions involving bulky bases?

Comment: The clue is in your title - "bulky bases" . Steric hindrance is a very real effect

Answer (score 1):

It is very tough, but cases of *t*-butoxide acting as a nucleophile are known, e.g. [*J. Org. Chem.* **2011,** *76* (24), 10129–10139](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo2019703):

> ***n*-Butyl-*tert*-butylether.** To a stirred solution of 10 g of potassium *tert*-butoxide (89 mmol) in 100 mL of anhydrous dimethylsulfoxide was added 12.1 g of *n*-butylbromide (89 mmol) dropwise at 10 °C. The reaction mixture was allowed to warm and stand under stirring for 8 h at room temperature. The mixture was distilled under vacuum at −20 °C. The crude was redistilled at normal pressure to collect 6 g (52%) of the fraction distilled at 75−78 °C as a colorless liquid.

Mechanistically, I don't see any other real possibility by which this occurs apart from an S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction. Of course, there will be significant amounts of competing elimination, and that is probably why the yield is not amazing.